# Make a data frame as one list in R

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a data frame of 228 rows and 228  columns. I want to subset this data frame without applying any conditions. instead, the subset will be based on the selected rows and column. and each subset will be an element of my list. e.g df is the data frame, I want the first element of my list to be df[1:6,1:6] and the second element is df[1:6,7:12] and so on until the last two elements which are df[223:228, 217:222] and  df[223:228, 223:228]. the length of my list should be 1444.
 I have tried for loop but it does not wor.
 my code is:

```
df<- data.frame(replicate(228,sample(0:234,228,rep=TRUE)))
f<- seq(1,nrow(df),6)
mylist<- list()
for(i in f){for( j in f){
  a<- (df[i:i+5,j:j+5])
}
  mylist[[i]]<- a
}
```

[image: my data frame is]

The expected results are:

[image]

Comment: Try `i:(i+5)` and `j:(j+5)`?

Comment: `mylist <- lapply(f, function(i) lapply(f, function(j) df[i:(i+5), j:(j+5)]))`.

Comment: Note: if you want just one list, not a list of lists, after the double `lapply`, do `mylist <- unlist(mylist, recursive = FALSE)`.

Comment: May I ask one more thing, after I do my analysis can I convert mylist again to dataframe with the same order as df. .

Comment: See the edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two functions do what the question and a follow-up [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154391/make-a-data-frame-as-one-list-in-r#comment102692393_58154391) ask for. The functions have an argument to allow for the dimensions of the result dataframe to be passed to `splitList`, defaulting to `n = 6`.

```
splitList <- function(DF, n = 6){
  f <- seq(1, nrow(DF), n)
  result_list <- lapply(f, function(j) lapply(f, function(i) DF[i:(i + n - 1), j:(j + n - 1)]))
  unlist(result_list, recursive = FALSE)
}

combineList <- function(X, n = 6){
  L <- length(X)
  M <- sqrt(L)
  f <- seq(1, L, M)
  tmp <- lapply(f, function(i){
    inx <- i:(i + M - 1)
    do.call(rbind, X[inx])
  })
  do.call(cbind, tmp)
}

mylist <- splitList(df)
d2 <- combineList(mylist)
identical(df, d2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Final clean up.

```
rm(d2)
```